# Extract numbers from a string into a list

Tags: python

I want to extract numbers in a string into a list but also include the other letters.

For example:

```
a='a815e8ef951'
```

Should result in the output:

```
['a',815,'e',8,'f',951]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about exponent notation, such as `[1e8]`?

Comment: Please search Google with your question before posting here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and `re` for this:

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r'(\d+|\D+)', 'a815e8ef951')
matches = [ int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in matches ]
# Output: ['a', 815, 'e', 8, 'ef', 951]
```

Comment: Right you are.  Updated with a list expansion and `isdigit`.

Comment: and that's a very good regex answer. you're lucky since it only deals with positive numbers, else it's very difficult to make it fit in a listcomp. Maybe you could explain that it works because regexes are greedy by default.

Comment: Agreed: but I figured it would be best to just answer the OP before dealing with additional complexity.  My thanks for the clarification on the OP’s question earlier.

Comment: you're welcome. You already did the hard part.

Answer (score 4):

You main use `itertools.groupby` along with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain
>>> a='a815e8ef951'

>>> [''.join(s) for _, s in groupby(a, str.isalpha)]
['a', '815', 'e', '8', 'ef', '951']
```

If you also want to convert the integer string to `int`, you have to modify the expression as:

```
>>> [''.join(s) if i else int(''.join(s)) for i, s in groupby(a, str.isalpha)]
['a', 815, 'e', 8, 'ef', 951]
```

In order to make the last expression little cleaner, you make move the `if` part to some function as:

```
def tranform_string(to_int, my_list):
    my_string = ''.join(my_list)
    return int(my_string) if to_int else my_string

new_list = [tranform_string(i, s) for i, s in groupby(a, str.isdigit)]
#                                       using `isdigit()` here  ^
```

where `new_list` will hold the required content.

Comment: good but OP also needs conversion to integer apparently

Comment: `groupby(a, lambda x: x.isalpha())` is the same as `groupby(a, str.isalpha)`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Umm, do you even need `chain`? It has no effect here.

Comment: @vaultah You are absolutely right. I am not sure why I thought of using that in the first place. May be I was thinking something at that time which was totally irrelevant. Thanks~